# Wireshark display filter for VLAN ID in Q-in-Q outer tag

Tags: wireshark, vlan, syntax

What is the syntax of a display filter that exclusively shows double-tagged frames whose outer tag has VID 129. I want to filter the S-tag. I do not want to filter the C-tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `ieee8021ad.id == 129`, but in case that's not the field you're looking for, the full list of ieee8021ad fields is listed on the Wireshark Display Filter Reference page for IEEE 802.1ad fields [here](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/i/ieee8021ad.html).  Note that using these fields requires that you're running at least version 1.0.0 of Wireshark and that the Ethertype is in fact 0x88a8 for IEEE 802.1ad.